# ERROR: iptables v1.4.21: icmp: option "--icmp-type" must be specified

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firewall, iptables

I trying to protect Smurf Attacks with iptables.
with

```
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type address-mask-request -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type timestamp-request -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp -m limit --limit 1/second -j ACCEPT
```

when I run this command

```
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp -m limit --limit 1/second -j ACCEPT
```

iptables show and error with

```
iptables v1.4.21: icmp: option "--icmp-type" must be specified
```

what is the problem ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that when using the icmp module, you must always specify one or more icmp types using --icmp-type.
This is becuase ICMP is used for a lot of legal things, like the "fragmentation needed", which would be bad to block, as it would lead to unreachable destinations.

Usually a smurf attack (which is a thing of the 90's), is done by making your server reply to a lot of echo requests. Echo requests are icmp-type 8 - so i'd suggest this instead:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -m limit --limit 1/second -j ACCEPT
```

this will allow 1 "icmp echo reply" per second. (Aka. "ping reply"). I'd personally set that limit a bit higher than 1/second, but this should work.

Comment: Thank you I'm new for iptables. Would you need to suggest the rule for secure the server?

Comment: If youre really new, i'd suggest starting the UFW, which gives you a a good starting point for a firewall. It allows for manual modification and adding stuff. And i wouldnt add this "Smurf" protection, but use generic icmp-type 8 blocking from untrusted sources. This is normal nowadays.